# JS logic - adding 2 multiselect checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just need help with a little JS logic as I'm pretty new to it. I have 2 seperate multiselect dropdown checkbox list user can select from. As of now they can choose no more than 5 from each. How could I set it up where it adds boths drop downs to only allow 5 TOTAL for both.

```
<select id="dropdown1" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
<select id="dropdown2" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
    header: "Choose up to 5 areas",
    click: function(event,ui){
              if( $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 5 ){
               return false;
          }},
      selectedList:5
    });
```

I'm assuming I would use the id's instead of just the ".multiselect" class then add them. Something like `#dropdown1+#dropdown2 > 5` in the if statement. I just simply don't know proper syntax to go about it someone could help me out.

If your not familiar with the jQuery widget I'm using:http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

per request user689

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
    header: "Choose up to 5 areas",
    click: function(event,ui){
            if($(".multiselect").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
                return this.value;    
                }).size() > 5){ return false;}},
      selectedList:5
    });
```

Comment: The source you referred to shows that getchecked returns an array of all checked values

Comment: so something like? `$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".multiselect").multiselect("getChecked")({
   header: "Choose up to 5 areas",
   click: function(event,ui){
    if( $(this).multiselect("widget").find("getChecked").length > 5 ){
        return false;
          }},
   selectedList:5
   });`

Comment: no, please refer to the syntax given in the link

Comment: I reiterate I'm new to js. I see what I need but dont know how to use it. Same with my 'solution' in my question. Knowing what vs knowing how.

Comment: Didn't my answer work for you?

Comment: that's true, you forgot to close the second } for the function add it after return false;} and do not forget the comma

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding 2 multiselect checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265300/adding-2-multiselect-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

You will show a message and also unselect the item when the number is more than 5.

**Javascript using Jquery**

```
$(".multiselect option").click(function(){      
        if($(".multiselect").children(":checked").length > 5){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).removeAttr("selected");
                alert("You can select only 5 items");
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I completely lose the functionality of widgets when I try this.

Comment: really? ohh, which library are you using for that?

Comment: https://raw.github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/1.13/src/jquery.multiselect.min.js

Comment: ok, let me see if I could implement that because I have never used that. If you get a solution use this and forget this comment haha. Good luck

Comment: the logic works. I only lose the checkbox part. It still validates 5 total for both except its only as a html 'multiselect' instead of using the widget.

Comment: Got it to work using your If logic since it worked...just changed beggining to `$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".multiselect").multiselect({
   click: function(event,ui){`

Comment: ohh , If I understood fine, you have added my function into your click method?  I had not enough time to test that using the library and try to fix that, but if it is working fine for you Congrats!! thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate question all over the place !
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194696/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget-cant-uncheck-checkbox/22277040#22277040  and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265300/adding-2-multiselect-checkboxes?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for using a method is:

```
$("#multiselect").multiselect("method_name");
```

As an example, to get an array of all clicked checkboxes:

```
var array_of_checked_values = $(".multiselect").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
return this.value;    
}).get();
```

In your case, you just want to get the number of checked boxes, i.e the length of the array:

```
if($(".multiselect").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
return this.value;    
}).size() > 5){ return false;}
```

The method you are using will access each checkbox on its own, and that would complicate things.

Comment: `if( $("this").multiselect("getChecked").length > 5 ){
               return false;` for some doesn't limit 5. If thats how I do it

Comment: @user3191137 what do you mean?

Comment: It doesn't work. I can select 6 or more in the first widget alone.

Comment: @user3191137 you are right, that's my fault. I've edited the answer

Comment: Trying to get it to work but still no luck with it. Loses all functionality and get a syntax error from '}' on the last line `$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".multiselect").multiselect({
   header: "Choose up to 5 areas",
   click: function(event,ui){
        if($(".multiselect").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
    return this.value;    
    }).size() > 5){ return false;}
          }},
   //selectedList:5
   });`

Comment: edited my comment with the syntax error. but confusing bc that bracket lines up with another one. removing it causes more syntax errors

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }. on the last line.

Comment: Ok, fixed syntax error. However the logic correctly prevents from more than 5 for the first widget but 2nd widget allows unlimited selections regardless of first widget.

Comment: I appreciate your time whether we can figure this out or not.

Comment: Can you [edit this](http://jsfiddle.net/SfeZt/) into a working JSFIDDLE demo so that everyone can collaborate? *I took/modified one of Eric Hynds' own jsFiddle demos, so framework should be correct. After editing, click UPDATE and post revised URL.*