# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget - Can't uncheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using 2 widgets that adds the selections and only allows the user to select 5 total between both dropdown widgets. Strangely once the 5 limit is reached, I can not uncheck the checkboxes! Anyone know why this is happening? I also noticed that if I say >5, the user can still choose 6 before is stopped. I'm having to use 4 to stop at 5?

```
<select id="dropdown1" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
<select id="dropdown2" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
    header: "Choose up to 5 areas",
    click: function(event,ui){
               if($(".multiselect").children(":checked").length > 4){               
                    return false;

        }},

      selectedList:5
    });
```

reference here for how I got to here: [JS logic - adding 2 multiselect checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190299/js-logic-adding-2-multiselect-checkboxes/21191121?noredirect=1#comment31914106_21191121)

UI widget i'm using:http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* Let me start again as I've recently learned some knowledge that changed what I thought I knew.

#### Why can't I uncheck checkboxes

You can't uncheck the checkboxes because you are preventing the default action by returning false from the click event handler if there are more than 4 boxes that are checked.

```
if ($('.multiselect').children(':checked').length > 4)
    return false;
```

This if statement evaluates to true if more than 4 checkboxes are checked. Since you don't allow checkboxes to be checked or unchecked, that means once 4 have been checked, they will always be checked (*until page refresh or programmatically uncheck*).

#### Why do I have to use 4 to stop at 5.

The reason for this isn't what I thought at first. I found out that when you click a checkbox, it's state is changed before entering the click event handler. However, if you return false from the click handler, it's state will revert to what it was previously.

What this means is that if you have 4 checkboxes checked, and you click a 5th checkbox, before you see the UI update with the 5th checked checkbox, programmatically, 5 checkboxes are checked. If you return false, this number will drop back to 4. If you return true, this number would stay at 5.

---

#### Solution

Here's the solution I came up with in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5efX/3/).

*Notice. I'm not using your multiselect plugin here, as I don't think this has anything to do with it.*

```
$('.multi-select').click(function (e) {
    if (!this.checked) return true;
    
    if ($('.multi-select:checked').length > 3)
        return false;
});
```

This code will only allow you to select 3 checkboxes at a time.

It checks if the clicked checkbox is not checked.. This means that the checkbox was previously checked. If the checkbox was checked previously, then we always want to allow the checkbox to be unchecked.

After that, it checks how many checkboxes are checked. I used 3 as the limit for how many checkboxes could be checked at a time. You could change (3) to (4) for your domain.

Here's your domain specific code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
        header: "Choose up to 5 areas",
        click: function (event, ui) {
            if (!this.checked) return true; //Allow previously checked checkboxes to be unchecked.
            
            if ($(".multiselect").children(":checked").length > 4) { //Only allow 4 checkboxes to be checked simultaneously.
                return false;
            }
        },
        selectedList:5
    });
});
```

Comment: ohh ok thanks. how could i overcome the return false then and still alow the user to unselect once limit is met?

Comment: still getting same result. put that in my click function before my other IF? keep everything else same?

Comment: This is allowing me to select unlimited check boxes.

Comment: for what its worth, 'event' and '!this.checked' are black and not blue for me. no console errors

Comment: If this last update doesn't work, then it must be something specific with your multiselect plugin that is interfering. In that case, I can't be of anymore use to you.

Comment: Think the bracket under return false needs to be removed? updating again or just change >=5 to >4?

Comment: @user3191137 There was an extra bracket. Try it now.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, but its not my library. In my past question link in my post got it to work for each by just returning false...thanks for the help though.

Comment: @user3191137 You can see it working fine in the jsFiddle that I posted. So, I'm not sure where we are amiss. Good luck.

Comment: @crush  Your jsFiddle is just separate checkboxes on their own.  The Multiselector which the OP is using is a dropdown script that Eric Hynds wrote specifically to work as a dropdown selector containing radios or checkboxes.  My jsFiddle answer actually answers the OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$("select").multiselect({ 
      selectedList:5,
      header: "Choose only Five items items!",
 click: function(e){
   if( $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 5 ){

       return false;
   } 
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP (user3191137) is using Eric Hynds [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) drop down selector.  The "click" method built in to the API assigns $(this) values specifically tied to the unique 'widget' id of each MultiSelect instance on the page.

This causes a problem trying to count the overall number of checkboxes across two or more selector instances on the page.   So a separate control is required which can keep track of the number of checkboxes checked overall.

My [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyRentals/DQ57x/) addresses this problem.

I have added a message layer into my example just to help show the status during the selections.

The way I solved this issue was having a separate variable counting the number of checks called "ClikCount". Checking this value either allows a selection or removes the selection if more than the max of 5 in this case.

**HTML example:**

```
<p class="message success">Check up to 5 checkboxes in total.</p>
<div class="box">
<select id="dropdown_1" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    </select></div>
<div class="box">
<select id="dropdown_2" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    </select></div>
```

**CSS used:**

```
.box{float:left;margin:10px 0;}
.multiselect{width:300px;}
.error { background:#FBE3E4; color:#8a1f11; border-color:#FBC2C4 }
```

**Javascript for Message and Counter:**

```
var warning = $(".message");
    var ClikCount = 0;
```

**Javascript to initialize all the Multi selectors:**

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
                multiple: true,
                height: '175px',
                //header: 'Choose up to 5 areas',
                noneSelectedText: 'Choose up to 5 areas Total',
                selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
                  return numChecked + ' of ' + numTotal + ' checked';
                },
                selectedList: false,
                show: ['blind', 200],
                hide: ['fade', 200],
                position: {
                    my: 'left top',
                    at: 'left bottom'
                }

            });
```

**Javascript to Count/Control the clicks overall in Multi selectors:**

*(UnComment alerts to step through the process)*

```
$("input[type = 'checkbox']").change(function () {
                var chekt = ($(this).is(':checked'));
                //alert("Is this.checked =" + chekt);
                if (chekt == true) {
                    if (ClikCount <= 4) {
                        warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Check a few boxes.");
                        ClikCount = ClikCount + 1;
                        //alert("count = " + ClikCount);
                    }
                    else {
                        warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You can only check five checkboxes!");
                        $(this).attr("checked",false);
                        //alert("count = " + ClikCount);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    ClikCount = ClikCount - 1;
                    warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Check up to 5 checkboxes in total.");
                }
            });
```