# JS - Adding 2 multiselect checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I'm using 2 jQuery UI widgets that adds the selections and only allows the user to select 5 total checkboxes between both dropdown widgets. I'm able to prevent to user from checking more boxes once 5 is hit but cannot uncheck. The below code does not put any restrictions. Any help would be appreciated.

UI widget i'm using:http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

```
<select id="dropdown1" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
<select id="dropdown2" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
        header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
        click: function (event, ui) {
            if (!this.checked) return true;

            if ($(".multiselect").children(":checked").length >= 5) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        selectedList:5
    });
});
```

removing the `return true` IF allows the user to only select 5 which also prevents user from unchecking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget - Can't uncheck checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194696/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget-cant-uncheck-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
        header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
        click: function (event, ui) {

            if (!this.checked && $(".multiselect").children(":checked").length >= 5) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        selectedList:5
    });
});
```

This way the condition to `return false` will only be met if the user clicked a non-checked box. If user clicks checked box, it will allow unchecking it.

Comment: Still unable to uncheck after 5 is met.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: not sure i'm able to since using multiple sources. js files to populate dropdown etc

Comment: See the same problem by the OP here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194696/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget-cant-uncheck-checkbox/22277040#22277040