# Adding 2 multiselect checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using 2 jQuery UI widgets that adds the selections and only allows the user to select 5 total checkboxes between both dropdown widgets. I'm able to prevent the user from checking more boxes once 5 is hit but cannot uncheck.

How could write this instead to create a variable and +1 or -1 every time a box is checked. Not allowing more than 5

UI widget i'm using:http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

```
<select id="dropdown1" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
<select id="dropdown2" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect({
        header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
        click: function (event, ui) {

            if (!this.checked && $(".multiselect").children(":checked").length >= 5) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        selectedList:5
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost works properly, but in your `click` function, `this` was returning the entire select list, so `!this.checked` would always be true because it was undefined.

If you use the `ui` variable, which is the option that was clicked, it will give you the proper result.

```
click: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.checked && $(".multiselect").children(":checked").length >= 5) {
            return false;
        }
    },
```

Here is an example of it working in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/3/

Comment: wow. been staring at it for a long time and didn't realize. thanks!

Comment: That's a good answer Bryan ! A lot less code than my answer for the OP on the OP's same problem described differently:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194696/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget-cant-uncheck-checkbox/22277040#22277040